# After using slice(), retrieve number of elements containing something within that slice

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to use slice to grab every X number of elements, and then return me the count within those items that contains a certain class.

So say I had

```
 $('.product').slice(0, 5)
```

and inside .product were some divs and lets say the 5 divs inside these product container div are

```
 <div class="col-a" />
 <div class="col-a" />
 <div class="col-b" />
 <div class="col-a" />
 <div class="col-a" />
```

I want it to return me with the count where the slices contain the class "col-b"

So in this case I want it to return me with amountWithColB  = 1

```
 var amountWithColB = $('.product').slice(0, 5) ... stuff here {}
```

Do I even need to slice? Can someone tell me the solution.

Comment: shouldn't `$('.product .col-b')` do if you are looking for a particular class inside `.product` element?

Comment: I am looking to do this for the first X elements until I reach the end of the list. So I need to do this for   slice(0, 5),  slice(6, 11), slice(12, 17) etc and for each one return me the number of inner div count containing a certain class. So I don't think that will work.

Comment: I see what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jQuery's `filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method and then take the `length` of the result:

```
var number_of_col_b_elems = $('.product div').slice(0, 5).filter(function() {
    return $(this).hasClass('col-b');
}).length;
```

Comment: That is what I wanted! Thank you for showing me filter()